# Ordinal arithmetic question

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

The question is: find $\delta \le \omega_1$ and $\rho \lt \omega$ such as $\omega_1 = \omega \cdot \delta + \rho$. My guess is that $\delta = \omega_1$ and $\rho = 0$, abut I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Can you tell me clearly what you want to find. Find the value or want to prove?

Comment: I want to find the value. If my guess is right, I want to see, how I can prove it.

Comment: @DarkArchon: What definition(s) of ordinal addition/ multiplication are you working with. It will almost certainly make a difference to the proof.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Prove that if $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are countable ordinals, then $\alpha\cdot\beta+\gamma$ is a countable ordinal.

Comment: Multiplication of countable number of countable sets is countable, as is addition. So if we are working with countable numbers, multiplication and addition saves countability. Because $\omega_1$ is least uncountable ordinal number, there must be $\omega_1$ in the expression. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.